# What template on numbers spreadsheet is suitable for the following need?

Tags: numbers

Using Numbers spreadsheet on iPhone, what template is suitable for the following need?
I want to follow the gaps between events occurring once a month on different dates, after inserting them into the software.
For example, I want to enter these dates 28/02 and then 15/03, and then 12/04, and get what is the gap between every 2 dates.

Comment: With the information provided, any template or even just a blank sheet would do. What do you want to do with the dates entered? Is this a diary/event log type of thing, do you want to calculate number of days between events, or something else? What have you tried so far, what makes the attempts you‘ve made fail to meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edit. There probably is no specific template for this, but there are date calculation functions one can use in formulas.